# Could not compile `lazy_static`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, hal

I'm having a hard time cross-compiling an embedded Rust project that worked before for a raspberry pi. I have all the needed deps in `Cargo.toml` but on doing:

`$ cargo build  --target thumbv7m-none-eabi`

I get the following error.

```
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
 --> /home/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/inline_lazy.rs:9:1
  |
9 | extern crate std;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
  |
  = note: the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target may not support the standard library
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `lazy_static` due to previous error
```

`$ rustup show`

```
installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

thumbv7m-none-eabi
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.64.0-nightly (38b72154d 2022-07-11)
```

Compilation used to work previously without lazy_static as a dependency in cargo.toml,now I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `lazy_static` depends on the rust standard library, which as the compiler told you

> may not be supported on the `thumbv7m-none-eabi` target

If you do not need the standard library in your project you can enable the `no-std` feature of `lazy_static` like this:

```ini
lazy_static = { version = "1.5.0", features = ["spin_no_std"] }
```

as described [here](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs/issues/35).

Comment: I think you're assuming that I'm using lazy_static crate,i'm not. The crate cant also support `!#[no_std]` as commented on the github issue.

Comment: If you don't use it then why did you put "Compilation used to work previously without lazy_static as a dependency in cargo.toml" in your question?

Comment: The issue has been closed more than 5 years ago, since then `!#[no_std]` is supported using the feature flag from above.